# How to calculate the ground truth of your own simple dataset for testing your SLAM Algorithm?

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, imu, algorithm, data-association

I have tested my SLAM algorithm on EuRoC, TUM and KITTI Datasets. But I would like to test on my own custom dataset. Moreover, I already rectify how to make my own dataset in TUM dataset format, but I didn't know how to calculate the ground truth of my own data set so that I calculate the accuracy of my SLAM algorithm.

Would kindly provide me any suggestions and recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you acquire your data. You can either manually label ground truth or use sensors such as GPS. I have used GPS data with RTK corrections (sub cm accuracy) as ground truth in the past. You could also place markers such as AR/april tags at known locations in your surroundings and use their measurements in your dataset as ground truth.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. for example I placed a black thick line on the white ground. I calculate it's distance and thickness with the help of tap. what you think it will help?

Comment: How do you deal with imprecise initial orientation? Slight errors in initial orientation well destroy evaluating the accuracy of your system